# On Proving $ a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 − 3a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2 + 2(a^ 2 + bc)(b ^2 + ca)(c^ 2 + ab) ≥ 0 $ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

On this problem, I made some observations and then started to solve.
Here one important note is that the inequality is trivial for $a,b,c\ge0$ and $a,b,c\le0$ and the inequality is symmetric.
Another observation: Working cases when one is negative or one is positive are the same.
Suppose WLOG $a\ge b\ge c$ when one is negative.
So we need to prove that$-$
$$ a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 − 3a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2 + 2(a^ 2 - bc)(b ^2 - ca)(c^ 2 + ab) ≥ 0  $$
Suppose to the contrary that WLOG $c\ge b\ge a$ when one is positive. So we need to prove that$-$
$$ a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 − 3a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2 + 2(a^ 2 - bc)(b ^2 - ca)(c^ 2 + ab) ≥ 0  $$
Which are the same. Working any could do. In both the cases, $a,b,c\ge0$. Say I do the first one.
$$ a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 − 3a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2 - 2 a^4 b c + 2 a^3 b^3 - 2 a^3 c^3 + 4 a^2 b^2 c^2 - 2 a b^4 c + 2 a b c^4 - 2 b^3 c^3 \ge 0 $$
$$ a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 + 2 a^3 b^3 + a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2+ 2 a b c^4 \ge 2 a^4 b c + 2 a^3 c^3 + 2 a b^4 c + 2 b^3 c^3 $$
How to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: $a^6 + b^6 + c^ 6 − 3a ^2 b^ 2 c^ 2 + 2(a^ 2 + bc)(b ^2 + ca)(c^ 2 + ab) =(a^3 + b^3 + c^3+ a b c )^2$.

Comment: @JohnB Did you use some machine? Well that is a very good observation.

Comment: @JohnB, perhaps you can turn your comment into an answer?